# SQL Server query, must not use subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using simple table/field names for the sake of simplicity:

```
SELECT A.a
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.a = B.a
WHERE B.a IS NULL
AND B.a NOT IN (
    SELECT B.a FROM B WHERE B.b = 'literal'
)
```

It's supposed to return the rows from table `A` where the `a` field does not exist in table `B` in those rows for which `B.b` equals a specific value (to be passed as a parameter).

```
A.a
-------
1
2
3

B.a      B.b
-----   -----
1       'literal'
1       'abc'
2       'def'
```

Considering that data, the query should return:

```
A.a
------
2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT A.a 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.a = B.a
    AND B.b = 'literal'
WHERE B.a IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7a44/1)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12a9a/2) with same data as @Ozzyberto

Comment: I'm not really sure what result could I expect from your answer, I tried it and I got 0 rows returned. I added an example, hope it helps clarify the desired result.

Comment: Oh I hadn't noticed the link, I checked it out and it seems to be right. There must be something wrong in my implementation. I'll do some more tests.

Comment: This does answer my question, however it seems my situation is a little more complicated than I first perceived it. I'll probably need to post another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table A (a int)

insert into A
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3

create table B (a int, b varchar(10))

insert into B
select 1, 'literal'
union all
select 2, 'abc'
union all 
select 3, 'def'

select A.a
from A
LEFT JOIN B
on A.a = B.a
where B.b <> 'literal' or B.b is null
```